# componentWillRecieveProps to getDerivedStateFromProps conversion

Tags: reactjs

Im refactoring my react application. I want to replace componentWillRecieveProps with getDerivedStateFromProps. Since, getDerivedStateFromProps doesn't support setState, I'm stuck with the following code. How can I convert this to getDerivedStateFromProps?

```
   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      if (nextProps.errors) {
         this.setState({ errors: nextProps.errors });
      }

      if (nextProps.profile.profile) {
         const profile = nextProps.profile.profile;

         profile.company = !isEmpty(profile.company) ? profile.company : '';
         profile.website = !isEmpty(profile.website) ? profile.website : '';
         profile.location = !isEmpty(profile.location) ? profile.location : ''; 

         // Set component fields state
         this.setState({
            company: profile.company,
            website: profile.website,
            location: profile.location
         });
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated state should be returned from `getDerivedStateFromProps` hook. In case a state shouldn't be updated, `null` is returned:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.errors) {
     return { errors: nextProps.errors };
  }

  if (nextProps.profile.profile) {
     const profile = nextProps.profile.profile;

     profile.company = !isEmpty(profile.company) ? profile.company : '';
     profile.website = !isEmpty(profile.website) ? profile.website : '';
     profile.location = !isEmpty(profile.location) ? profile.location : ''; 

     return {
        company: profile.company,
        website: profile.website,
        location: profile.location
     };
  }

  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need Derived State, you could use componentDidUpdate() method for this. Unlike getDerivedStateFromProps this is not static, so you should be able to use this.setState().